# Button under a list view

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview and I use a button + textview to add element in the listview. I would like the button to be under the list view and if the list contains enough element to be scrollable, and I want the button to do alignParentBottom so that he is always visible on screen. 
I have this xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/lin"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:background="@drawable/my_button_xml_small"
       android:layout_height="100dp">

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">


           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/lbl_title"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
               android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/confirm_action"
               android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/confirm_action"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:text="Ajouter une option"
               android:textSize="40sp" />

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/confirm_action"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:text="CONFIRMER"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


       </RelativeLayout>


   </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lbl_name_options"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/lin"
        android:hint="Entrez le nom de l'option"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_options"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/lbl_name_options"
        android:layout_above="@id/lbl_add_options"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lbl_add_options"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:hint="Entrer une option à ajouter"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_add_option"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_option"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/lbl_add_options"
        android:text="Ajouter"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

But the problem is that if there is not element on the list, the button is alignparentbottom and it takes the whole screen for nothing

Can someone help me?

It gives this result :

[image]

But when there is only a few items like this, I would it to be like this : 
[image]
And when there is enough items to be scrollable, it should be like this : 
[image]

EDIT

It works but if I don't put the padding in looks like this :

[image]

But if I put it, the problem is that the keyboard will hide to much elements from the list :

[image]

But I have a bit solved it by adding in the manifest : android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
but problem with that is that it pushed all the screen so I can't access all element from the list cause it doesn't scroll

Comment: provide your expected screen image for better understanding. And one thing, you have set the `btn_add_option` button as `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: I've answered below, please check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check bellow layout, I've changed little bit to work as per your expectation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button_xml_small"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="100dp">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/confirm_action"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/confirm_action"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Ajouter une option"
                    android:textSize="40sp"/>

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/confirm_action"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="CONFIRMER"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lbl_name_options"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/lin"
            android:hint="Entrez le nom de l'option"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="35dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_options"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/lbl_name_options"
            android:paddingBottom="100dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/list_options"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/lbl_add_options"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_add_option"
                android:hint="Entrer une option à ajouter"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_add_option"
                android:layout_height="50dp"/>
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_add_option"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:text="Ajouter"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: less item screenshot][image: more items screenshot]
and activity as follows: here you can add more items to check full screen mode.

```
class TTActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        var array = arrayOf("Melbourne", "Vienna")

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.tt)
            val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,
                R.layout.item, array)

            val listView:ListView = findViewById(R.id.list_options)
            listView.setAdapter(adapter)
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works thanks. But I have edited the question with an "issue" I found a solution but it is not perfect, if u have any better idea?
Still I don't really understand in your xml what is the "special command" which makes the edit text alignParentBottom when the number of items in the list is big enough

Comment: Actually I thought it works but the keyboard isn't following the the edit text so it's hard coded.. You need to set up : android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: This is a different issue. You can set  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` or  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` as per your expectation, it should work because there is a listview and you can scroll to see hidden items.

Answer (score 0):

You can try layout-weight like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put the listView and Buttom in the same container LinearLayout and use the

Simply Provide "layout_weight = 1" of ListView.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [Constraint Layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) just check little bit the documentation, it is so simple and easy to use